# How can I authenticate to my flutter app using metamask?

Tags: flutter, authentication, metamask

I need to connect my flutter application with my metamask wallet account to log in, I've tried libraries like walletConnect v1 and it doesn't seem to work anymore, I've also tried version two but I can't understand the documentation

I have tried with the walletConnect v1 and v2 packages, also, also with some other libraries that I found in pub.dev, so far I have not been able to achieve authentication

Comment: Hi there. Wallet Connect v1 has been shutdown so that wont work.
Did you manage to implement it now?

Comment: So far I have been able to get a connection, but I also need to make a signature request and have it return the same, but I cannot make it return the signature, it only shows me the parameters of the request

Comment: I am able to get a public address from the metmask action sheet after user approves. But I need to have a signature generated using public_address and nonce (from our backend) and then use that signature to get authenticated user from our backend. But I had had no luck generating a valid signature (tried keccak256 and EthSigUtil)